# Is this the right solution?

Tags: logic

please state whether this is true/false:

Let p = true,
 q = false,
 r = true

$\neg r \implies (p \wedge \neg q) = true$ [correct?]

false $\implies$ true that will be true right?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes. $A \rightarrow B$ is the same as $\neg A \vee B$, so if $A$ is false, $A \rightarrow B$ is true.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. In a way you wrote more than necessary. Since $\lnot r$ is false, it is irrelevant that $p\land \lnot q$ is true. The implication would be true even if $p\land \lnot q$ happened to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion, and reasoning, are correct. However, you did more truth evaluations than necessary. Since $\lnot r$ is false, it is irrelevant that $p\land \lnot q$ is true. The implication would hold even if $p\land \lnot q$ happened to be false.